# Change <div> direction with Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have the following code:

```
<div class="row">
  @for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
   <div class="col-md-4">
    @Html.Raw(i)
   </div>
  }
 </div>
```

with this output:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
```

Instead of showing the numbers in rows I want to show them in columns like this:

```
0 2 4
1 3 5
```

If I put both `div` outside the loop i get everything in one column and not three.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with razor, but I think that should solve your problem.

```
<div class="row">
  @for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      @for(int i = j; i < 6; i += 2) {
          <div class="col-md-4">
               @Html.Raw(i)
          </div>
       }
  } 
</div>
```

Comment: With 6 nums works, but if I have 2,3 than doesn't work. Or lets say I have a `List<string> test` with `{"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"}` the output is `Test1 Test3 Test2`

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: First Column: Test1(row 1) Test2(row 2) and Test3 in the second column